# Install rdatatable from source on mac catalina

Tags: r, data.table

I have 'meticulously' followed the rdatatable's [mac installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). I also tried to follow [this blog post](https://luispuerto.github.io/luisspuerto.net-testing/blog/2018/01/12/install-r-100-homebrew-edition-with-openblas-openmp-my-version/) to install r via homebrew and then install packages from source.

However, there seems to be a problem that I cannot figure out by myself. Could you please help me out here? I recently downgraded my mac from Big Sur to Catalina. I was able to install packages from source both on Big Sur and previously on Catalina.

```r
install.packages("data.table", type = "source", repos = "https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table")
#> Warning in install.packages("data.table", type = "source", repos = "https://
#> Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table"): installation of package 'data.table' had non-
#> zero exit status
```

```r
char    *cgetcap(char *, const char *, int);
                                    ^
                                     _Nullable
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:34: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
char    *cgetcap(char *, const char *, int);
                                    ^
                                     _Nonnull
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:6: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
char    *cgetcap(char *, const char *, int);
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:6: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
char    *cgetcap(char *, const char *, int);
        ^
          _Nullable 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:6: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
char    *cgetcap(char *, const char *, int);
        ^
          _Nonnull 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:283:19: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
int      cgetent(char **, char **, const char *);
                      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:283:19: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
int      cgetent(char **, char **, const char *);
                      ^
                       _Nullable

.
.
.
                                                               ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:328:57: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
            int (^ _Nonnull __compar)(const void *, const void *) __sort_noescape)
                                                               ^
 
                                          ^
                                            _Nonnull 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:359:13: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
extern char *suboptarg;         /* getsubopt(3) external variable */
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:359:13: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
extern char *suboptarg;         /* getsubopt(3) external variable */
            ^
              _Nullable 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:359:13: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
extern char *suboptarg;         /* getsubopt(3) external variable */
            ^
              _Nonnull 
215 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [assign.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] digest_0.6.27     assertthat_0.2.1  magrittr_2.0.1    reprex_1.0.0     
#>  [5] evaluate_0.14     highr_0.8         rlang_0.4.10      stringi_1.5.3    
#>  [9] cli_2.3.1         fs_1.5.0          rmarkdown_2.7     tools_4.0.4      
#> [13] stringr_1.4.0     glue_1.4.2        xfun_0.22         yaml_2.2.1       
#> [17] compiler_4.0.4    htmltools_0.5.1.1 knitr_1.31
```

Comment: It might be not exactly relevant to your case, but here you can find source code based approach for R, clang and rJava: https://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/

Comment: I thought the `_Nonull` and `_Nullable` were among the 215 warnings, I don't see the actual errors in the text you provided. Can you fish through the output and find the (two) messages that indicate the actual errors? (It's quite common to have warnings like that in compilation. "Ideally" all warnings would be removed, but I suspect that's a matter of diminishing returns and/or chasing different compilers.)

Comment: (FYI, I don't have macos and may not be able to fix the errors, but perhaps identifying the specific errors will help find relevant posts and/or solutions listed elsewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

The installations worked with gcc!
Commented out the clang compiler options and tried with gcc and installed data.table from source with openmp support.

```
# # if you downloaded llvm manually above, replace with your chosen NEW_PATH/clang
# LLVM_LOC = /usr/local/opt/llvm
# CC=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang -fopenmp
# CXX=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang++ -fopenmp
# # -O3 should be faster than -O2 (default) level optimisation ..
# CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
# CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
# LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
# CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

# GCC (Official GNU fortran) ver

 LOC = /usr/local/gfortran
 CC=$(LOC)/bin/gcc -fopenmp
 CXX=$(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp
 CXX11 = $(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp # for fst package
 
 CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
 CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
 LDFLAGS=-L$(LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,-I$(LOC)/lib
 CPPFLAGS=-I$(LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```